# WebStorm + meteor setup: Unresolved meteor template or helper, in templates with "#each" and "this"

Tags: templates, meteor, webstorm, setup-project, jetbrains-ide

I wanted to setup the meteor project in WebStorm.
But in every template with `{{#each xxx}} {{this}} {{/each}}` WebStorm shows me this error: "Unresolved meteor template or helper".
How to Setup an Meteor project right in Webstorm?

i used meteor plugin. Created new meteor project, with template: `todos`.
e.g. by /client/templates/auth-join.html line 18 the `this` is highlighted with such error.

Comment: I czeched out WebStorm a few days ago; I came to realize that I prefer Atom.

Comment: I am using Webstorm and I never have problems, unless I have bugs :) But here is a section you might want to read: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-meteor.html

Comment: The problem with 'this' is resolved in the latest meteor plugin version (you can try it in WebStorm 11 EAP). Anyway it is just a warning not an error